# Filtering by properties in OneToMany relation table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with filtering the table by properties in the table with which it is related to OneToMany, preview

```
class A {

@OneToMany(fetch.. mappedBy)
private List<B> b;

}
class B {
private String property1;
private String property2;
}
```

Using the specification I make a join, it adds a Predicate which says we only want to fetch those with property1 = "ABC", (root.join(B).get(property1).equals("ABC"). In this case, it will fetch me all objects of class A that have at least one B record that meets the given criteria. My problem is that I would also like Class B objects to be filtered by the given criteria if the criteria are for class B, how to go about it? At the moment, I have two queries, one to download all A that meet the given criteria, the second query to download all B that are in relation to the found A. I would like to ask you to indicate which way to choose to solve this challenge :)

I tried different fetchmodes etc but didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Since the result of the query are managed entities, filtering the collection is problematic. When your transaction finishes, the filtered out elements might be removed so it's important that you immediately detach all entities after such a query e.g. via `entityManager.clear()`.

You can try to cast a fetch to a join i.e. `((Join<?, ?>) root.fetch("b")).get("property")`, but be careful.

I'd rather suggest you to look into Hibernate filters or use a DTO model for this. For the DTO approach, I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(A.class)
public interface ADto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("b[property1 = 'ABC']")
    Set<BDto> getB();

    @EntityView(B.class)
    interface BDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getProperty2();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ADto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ADto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ADto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!